# Update tooltip while its shown?

Tags: javascript

Is there way update the text in tooltip that browser shows based on `title` attribute of an element while it's being shown?

I fetch data from server to display in tooltip, unfortunately fetch is async so I need to "delay" somehow displaying the tooltip until data is received. If I simply change `title` attribute, the change is not reflected in the tooltip until cursor moved.

```js
test.addEventListener("mouseenter", e => {
  pause = true;
  setTimeout(a => { //fetch emulation, 1sec delay
    test.title = data
  }, 1000);
});

//irrelevant content
test.addEventListener("mouseleave", e => pause = false);

let data, pause = false;
setInterval(a => {
  if (pause) return;
  data = performance.now();
  timer.textContent = data;
}, 300);
```

```html
<div id="test" title="initial">Tooltip should show <span id="timer"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You’ll likely have to pull in a tooltip package and render it

Comment: seems like a basic ajax feature

Comment: as said above already but putting it in another words: the answer is no. the "tooltip" feature offered by the browser that relies on the value of the title attribute, cannot be refreshed while it's showing up. So you have to implement your own strategy using a div that will behave as the tooltip you are expecting and updating its content. There are several ready to use solutions like for example(!! and among many including your own) bootstrap tooltips

Comment: @Roland Yes, updating the `title` attribute can be done at any time, also in the success handler of an ajax request. But that doesn't necessarily mean, that the browser will immediately reflect these changes, and update the currently rendered tooltip. If you want to make sure of that, you shouldn't rely on the built-in rendering of the `title` attribute, but either implement tooltips yourself or use some existing library.